# How to check whether the data from excel 3rd character must be a '-' in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing the checking data from excel by python. so I am needed to check whether the 3rd character of the data have "-" or not. For example: RE-32456. The data in the excel must have "-" for the 3rd character in each cell.

I use this coding but the result are not as I expect:

columnA=df.ProjectID

if s1 = columnA[2:] + '-' + columnA[:8]
print(s1)

[This is the data in the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbjpV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you access the data, but if it's in a 2d array you can just do:

```
assert excel[i, j][2]=="-"
```

Comment: may I know what i and j refer for?

Comment: The row and column of the data you want to check. You can load the excel file using [pands](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or another [module handling excel with python](https://www.python-excel.org/). Then you can access the row and columns you want to check by iterating over the file with i and j. Suppose you want to check the 2nd column you can do `for i in range(excel.shape[0]): assert excel[i, 1]=="-"` with excel the file loaded using one of the previously mentioned module